# Validation for input value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

> I'm trying to use validation on input field for Employee salary
>   calculation form by using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

The calculation code works fine, however it can't validate input field before proceeding with calculation.

Here the code.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["employeename"]["employeeno"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Please fill up Empty field");
    return false;
  }
}

function paySalary() {
    var employeeName = document.getElementById("employeename").value;
 var employeeNo = document.getElementById("employeeno").value;
    var employeeHours = document.getElementById("hours").value;
 var HoursRate = document.getElementById("rate").value;

    if (employeeHours <= 40) {
      var regtime = HoursRate * employeeHours;
      var overtime = 0.00;
      var salary = regtime;
    } else if (employeeHours > 40) {
       var regtime = (HoursRate * 40);
       var overtime = ((HoursRate * 1.5) * (employeeHours - 40));
       var salary = (regtime + overtime);
    }
 alert("Paid ammout for " + employeeName + " is for RM " + salary );
}
```

```html
<body>
<form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)" method="post">
<label>Employee Name :</label>
<input id="employeename" value=""><br>

<label>Employee No   :</label>
<input id="employeeno" value=""><br>

<label>Rate of pay   :</label>
<input id="rate" value=""><br>

<label>Hours Work    :</label>
<input id="hours" value=""><br>

<br>
<button id="submit" onclick="paySalary()" >Submit</button>
</form>
<br>
<br>
</body>
```

Comment: Why not rely on the default validation. You can just add the `required` attribute before form submitting

Comment: @Denis Ryan what type of validation do you need ?

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan  Client-side validation. I try for Alert Dialog Box for the validation but the code didnt function.

Comment: @SuperDJ thank you for the suggestion. I hope to get the alert dialog box validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paySalary() function will be executed as soon as you click the submit button and before the form validation. What you can do is writting the  validateForm() inside the paySalary() function. If the conditions pass the test then continue..

```js
function validateForm() {

  var x = document.getElementById("employeeno").value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Please fill up Empty field");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function paySalary() {
    // If the form is not valid: stop execution
    if(!validateForm()) {
      return;
    }
    
    var employeeName = document.getElementById("employeename").value;
 var employeeNo = document.getElementById("employeeno").value;
  var employeeHours = document.getElementById("hours").value;
 var HoursRate = document.getElementById("rate").value;

  if (employeeHours <= 40) {
    var regtime = HoursRate * employeeHours;
    var overtime = 0.00;
    var salary = regtime;
  } else if (employeeHours > 40) {
     var regtime = (HoursRate * 40);
     var overtime = ((HoursRate * 1.5) * (employeeHours - 40));
     var salary = (regtime + overtime);
  }
 alert("Paid ammout for " + employeeName + " is for RM " + salary )
}
```

```html
<body>
<form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return paySalary()" method="post">
<label>Employee Name :</label>
<input id="employeename" value="Bob"><br>

<label>Employee No   :</label>
<input id="employeeno"><br>

<label>Rate of pay   :</label>
<input id="rate" value="0"><br>

<label>Hours Work    :</label>
<input id="hours" value="0"><br>

<br>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<br>
<br>
</body>
```